# Testing recurrences and orders in strings matlab

Tags: r, matlab, statistics

I have observed nurses during 400 episodes of care and recorded the sequence of surfaces contacts in each.

I categorised the surfaces into 5 groups 1:5 and calculated the probability density functions of touching any one of 1:5 (PDF).

```
PDF=[ 0.255202629   0.186199343 0.104052574 0.201533406 0.253012048]
```

I then predicted some 1000 sequences using:

```
for i=1:1000 % 1000 different nurses
    seq(i,1:end)=randsample(1:5,max(observed_seq_length),'true',PDF);
end
```

eg.

```
 seq =     1     5     2     3     4     2     5     5     2     5

stairs(1:max(observed_seq_length),seq) hold all
```

[image]

I'd like to compare my empirical sequences with my predicted one. What would you suggest to be the best strategy or property to look at?

Regards,

EDIT: I put `r` as a tag as this may well fall more easily under that category due to the nature of the question rather than the matlab code.

Comment: Just a side point, `seq(i,1:end)` is the same as `seq(i,:)` in Matlab. What about something like the Kolmogorov-Smirnov statistic? See http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest2.html or http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kstest.html

Comment: @dan ie that the values of 1:5 are distributed similarly in both distributions? im also interested in the sequence order too...

Comment: I think you're better off asking this in a statistics forum. It's not really a programming problem but rather the underlying concept. Try *Statistics* or *Cross Validated*, you might get a more insightful answer.

Comment: @Dan It did cross my mind. I suppose I was trying to ask it from a programmers point of view (ie testing recurrences and orders in strings)

Comment: But tbh I think since you are only using a PDF to generate the values, there is no information guiding the sequence order so I think testing to see if the PDFs are well matched is all you really can do. If `seq = 1 5` is different from `seq = 5 1` then I don't think your approach is correct

Comment: @Dan point noted! Then by definition the PDFs would coincide because we are sampling from the same PDF essentially. So suppose I had a method of generating an ordered sequence (a Markov Chain) then how would I compare strings? You see I wanted to avoid using any jargon but lets suppose I have been able to generate an ordered sequence. Does that change anything?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/27618/discussion-between-dan-and-user1134241)